# Why was my question removed from the HNQ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, questions, hot-questions

My famous question "[Why are Kinder Surprise Eggs illegal in the USA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40621/why-are-kinder-surprise-eggs-illegal-in-the-usa)" became a hot network question, but the next day a moderator had removed it from the HNQ, which is irreversible.

[image: Removed from HNQ :(]

So, why was my question removed from the HNQ list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Questions on the HNQ is often the first impression people will get about our site. Ideally, only the best of our content should appear on that list.

Your question, while not bad, shows zero prior research effort. A quick look at the relevant Wikipedia article is enough to answer it. In fact, that's all the accepted answer does, point you to Wikipedia.

I removed the question because I do not think that is the content we should be advertising. It's hardly representative of the site, and it creates the false impression that we welcome ill-research questions. We don't, we really don't. Had your question been about a less affable subject, you'd probably get a fair amount of down-votes and wouldn't make it in the HNQ in the first place.

Comment: As a technical sidenote: Please use `@username` in comments to get someone's attention. Your [comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/40621/why-are-kinder-surprise-eggs-illegal-in-the-usa#comment157751_40621) did not generate an inbox notification and I completely missed it. More details here: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/162704)

Comment: Also, if you want to contact a Moderator specifically, you can flag the question as "In Need of Moderator Intervention" and ask your question there. That kind of flag carries no punishment and you can even call it on your own questions.

Comment: @divibisan Moderator flags are for *requesting action*, not *asking questions*. A meta post is the proper way to ask questions.