# What constitutes a "low-research-effort" question?

Tags: support

This is a follow-up to [this](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4140/why-was-my-question-removed-from-the-hnq) meta post.

> Your question, while not bad, shows zero prior research effort. A quick look at the relevant Wikipedia article is enough to answer it. In fact, that's all the accepted answer does, point you to Wikipedia.

What **specifically** causes a question to be considered as a "low-research-effort" question?  That question got some downvotes, and the tooltip for the downvote says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

My guess is:

### No research effort

> - Questions that can be answered by simply reading the first link when researching it on Google and/or by reading a Wiki article (ex. Wikipedia)
> - Question is duplicate

### Unclear

> - Question is unclear
> - Question is too broad
> - Question is a VLQ question

### Not useful

> - Off-topic
> - Spam or offensive
> - Opinion-based
> - Answer to the question is extremely obvious in the common sense and/or the question is too basic
> - etc. (Other reasons - ex. Question was written in bad faith)

Comment: Related: [Should be try to get askers to include references in their questions?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2544/2984)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Up and down) Voting is subjective.

Different people have different standards, and everyone is free to interpret the guidance in the tooltip in their own way.